# For Each in LINQ Select

Tags: c#, linq

Just a quick question for people who know the inner workings of .Net better than me ::- ). I am JUST MAKING SURE that I understand something.

The way I see it, when you run a LINQ in a foreach, the LINQ enumerator is evaluated (run), it returns a collection and the foreach proceeds on that collection. But... still, I am unsure:

```
foreach (VCCTreeItem ti in (from treeItems in TreeItems select treeItems))
```

Is the LINQ statement re-evaluated (executed) at each loop? I would think (and hope) that NO. However, when doing operations with a collection in a `foreach`, you get error messages at run-time if the collection is modified. Which led me to believe that something fishy may be happening behind the scenes. I never had the time to disassemble / check this in detail, so this is why I'm asking you this. I'm sure some of you know the answer from the top of their head ::- D.

Oh, and I think I can ask the same question about:

```
foreach (VCCTreeItem ti in TreeItems)
```

If TreeItems is a property in whose `get` I do some operations, the property will be evaluated, returned as a value and the foreach will operate on that value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IEnumerable` is not reevaluated. A `foreach` statement like this:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> enumerable = ...;
foreach (Foo f in enumerable) {
    ...
}
```

corresponds to this (EDIT: `enumerator` is also put in a `using` block, as shown by @Double Down):

```
IEnumerable<Foo> enumerable = ...;
IEnumerator<Foo> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    Foo f = enumerator.Current;
    ...
}
```

So if you have some costly operation that produces the collection you're looping over, it's not a problem; it will only be produced once. In LINQ, though, as @Double Down says, most results are produced lazily - so the call to `GetEnumerator()` does almost nothing, while the result is produced incrementally by each call to `MoveNext()`. Overall, this is about as time consuming as producing the entire list in one operation, but it conserves memory (an actual `List` containing all elements is never produced; you get one element at a time, then discard it).

Comment: No problem. By the way, an interesting learning exercise would be to implement a pair of `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` classes yourself. For instance, you could create a class whose constructor takes two ints `a` and `b`, and when it is enumerated, it produces all integers between `a` and `b`. In addition to learning more about how those interfaces are used, you could use a `foreach` on an instance of your class and see for yourself that `GetEnumerator()` only gets called once. :-)

Comment: That's a good idea ::- D. But when you're in my shoes, trying to build a huge project and achieve your dreams while living on an indie budget and most of the stuff you do is free & open source, life tends to remind you that time is precious. So I will take your answer without further verification ::- ). I'm not lazy, I'm just time-crushed. I know, everybody is. But I do some Open Source stuff as well https://sourceforge.net/projects/mousenitor/ ... besides my other projects which for now don't make a lot of money either (read 0). *sigh*, I don't know why I just had this justification trip, LOL

Comment: I see - good luck with your projects, then, and keep your eyes open for an opportunity to implement `IEnumerable` in production code ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Linq is doing late bound evaluation (using the yield keyword).  It's evaluated for only  the next item when you call MoveNext() in an IEnumerator, it's not recomputed from scratch in each move next call.

As you already know, your foreach loop evaluates to

```
using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Loop body.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me sleep better ::- D.